# How do I use JQuery's "load" function to get the wanted data in a variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to know how to use jQuery's "load" AJAX function to get the wanted data in a variable?
Should look like this in the end:
    var data = "->load data<-";

Thanks!

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
});

Comment: Load doesn't work like that , you could do it but its a bit of a round about way . Just use .post or .get and put the 'data' in a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The load method is there to directly append the data to a jQuery element. Instead you could use [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to issue a `GET` or `POST` request. Eg.

```
$.get("url.to/load/from", { param: "Hello" }, function(data){
    var loadedData = data;
});
```

Comment: Totally forgot about the other ajax methods.. ;)
Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit  difficult to say what you're asking here...
There are 2 `load` functions in jQuery's core.

1. If you want to get some data through an ajax call, you should take a look at other jquery ajax methods such as `get`,`post`,`ajax`... and so on:

   ```
   var data = null;
   $.get(url,params,function(response){
       data = response;
   });
   ```
2. If you want to listen to an `load` event (such as when the window or an image is loaded) you can do something like :

   ```
   var data = null;
   $(window).load(function(){
         data = 'some data';
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ or jQuery.post with callbacks to store data into variable.

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

`.load` is specifically a convenience wrapper to place data directly into a DOM element, without needing to go through custom functions to do so. Use one of the other AJAX methods, like [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented jQuery post

```
$.post("loadurl.php", { param: value },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });

 });
```